# How to use custom footer template in a site-plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, page-template

I have a site-plugin to centralize most of the theme customization. I want to override the default *footer.php* template with a *customfooter.php* (removes the *Proudly Powered by WordPress*) stored inside the /plugins directory structure. I found [this resource on StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257662/page-templates-from-plugin-not-working-after-upgrading-wp-to-4-7-or-upper-versio#new-answer?newreg=5b288fc8c76248b59434222b98e258ae), [one here](https://9seeds.com/including-templates-inside-a-plugin/), and tried some. Obviously, I am making errors. Could someone please advise how to achieve this without touching the theme files / directories?

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'force_customization', 101 );
function force_customization( $newtemplate ) {
       if ( is_singular( 'footer' ) ) {
        $newtemplate = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'customization/customfooter.php';
     }
     return $newtemplate;
}
```

Any / all help is welcome.

Kind regards

Abhijeet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override header / footer templates from a plugin, you'll have to change the theme.

`theme_page_templates` can be used to change the general template for the post type `page`. That template then uses get_header() and get_footer(), which in turn include `header.php` / `footer.php` (optionally header-$name.php, if a parameter has been passed to get_header(), same for get_footer()).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Just to clarify - Are you pointing to a constraint for     theme_page_templates     or instead suggesting that     footer.php     cannot be overridden using any WordPress method? For instance, I tried using the     is_page_template     too, but it does not work. I am a newb with WP and coding and trying to centralize customization to ease ongoing management of my site. Is it possible to achieve? Any / all suggestions are welcome. Thank you

Comment: The latter. You cannot make WP use a different file than footer.php from outside the theme. If you're working in the theme/child-theme, you can use get_footer("special") and it will prefer footer-special.php over footer.php (but still fall back on footer.php if the other one doesn't exist). You'll have to create a child theme and make your modifications there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been trying to work this for some time and your response helps to move on :) Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I added a custom header and footer to my custom plugin.

**plugin.php**:

```
function _get_header($name, $require_once = TRUE, $args = []) {
  return load_template(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/{$name}.php", $require_once, $args);
}

function _get_footer($name, $require_once = TRUE, $args = []) {
  return load_template(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/{$name}.php", $require_once, $args);
}
```

**Create your templates**:

- `/includes/my-header.php`
- `/includes/my-footer.php`

In your template file, e.g. **single-custom.php**:

```
_get_header('my-header'); //<- name of file without extension.
_get_footer('my-footer'); //<- name of file without extension.
```

Here are the twentytwentyone files from WP:

- Header:
  https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/header.php
- Footer:
  https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/footer.php